# CSS Background Image Not Adapting With Screen Size

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am a relatively new at HTML / CSS. I have started to develop a website but my main "hero" image doesn't adapt properly with smaller pages and leaves white space. If you could help me diagnose the problem it would be greatly appreciated.

*/ css */

```
#intro {
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    height: 66%;
    background: url("../images/intro2.jpg"); center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    top:10%;
    background-position: 0px -150px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: 100%;
}
#intro .wrap{
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
#intro .content{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

*/ html */

```
<section id="intro">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="content">
        <h1 id="welcome"> Your number one choice for music <br> in the south coast </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The site can also be viewed [Here](http://insidiousfm.x10.mx)

Comment: You have two `background-size` properties in `#style`; which one do you want to keep? Also, the `background-position` looks suspicious; are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: The first background statement also looks not quite kosher. I might be wrong, but I believe there should be no semicolon after the url(..) statement.

Comment: background-position: cover;    dont set width or height of bg-image... should be ok

Comment: Also change south coast to a different color text, cant see it ...look at @media queries for your css . https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: @Careen Color? What color?

Comment: You have an error in your CSS. `background: url("../images/intro2.jpg"); center center no-repeat;` no need for the `;` after `url()`. Try removing that.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would accomplish this:

CSS

```
html,body{
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
}

.section{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:purple;
}

.section img{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    min-height:100%;
    display:block;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    min-width:100%;  
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="section">
   <img src="http://th02.deviantart.net/fs42/PRE/f/2009/133/a/0/Rainy_Landscape_STOCK_by_wyldraven.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="section">
</div>
```

Example: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/dclappert/pen/GJpGYE)

You will notice that no matter how big or small you scale the page (and therefore the section), the image will always expand to fill the parent container.